# Extracting Content after a Numbered List

Tags: python, regex, string

is there a way to extract the content after the numbered list in Python? For eg.

> 1. A user interface (ui) object: The user interface (ui) object governs the layout and appearance of the app.
> 2. A server function: The server function contains the instructions to build the app.
> 3. A call to the shinyApp function: The shinyApp function creates Shiny app objects from an explicit UI/server pair.

I would like to extract the content after 1., 2., and 3. I've tried the following but it doesn't capture everything.

```
import re
content = re.search(r'[0-9]\..+', text)
text[1533:1639]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group to get the data after the digits and dot at the start.

If you also want to match for example `10.` at the start, you can repeat the digit 1 or more times `[0-9]+`

Capture the rest after the digits and dot on the first line, and then also capture all following lines that do not start with the digits dot pattern.

```
^[0-9]+\. (.*(?:\n(?![0-9]+\.).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]+\.`  Match 1+ digits and `.`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

    - `\n(?![0-9]+\.).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with digits and `.`
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJSatK/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Dxzm79)

**Example**

```
import re

pattern = r"^[0-9]+\. (.*(?:\n(?![0-9]+\.).*)*)"

s = ("1. A user interface (ui) object: The user interface (ui) object governs the layout and \n"
    "appearance of the app.\n"
    "2. A server function: The server function contains the instructions to build the app.\n"
    "3. A call to the shinyApp function: The shinyApp function creates Shiny app objects from \n"
    "an explicit UI/server pair.")
    
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

**Output**

```
[
'A user interface (ui) object: The user interface (ui) object governs the layout and \nappearance of the app.',
'A server function: The server function contains the instructions to build the app.',
'A call to the shinyApp function: The shinyApp function creates Shiny app objects from \nan explicit UI/server pair.'
]
```